# Android studio no longer detecting device after update

Tags: android-studio, adb

A few hours ago, my Android studio was working very fine. I could write, build and run on my test device (TECNO K7).

I decided to update my Android Studio to 3.5. The whole process went well except that **I cannot find my device among the list of devices any longer**. I have also tried with multiple devices, I got the same outcome. When I click on the run-button, the app runs on the Pixel 2 emulator. However, I want it to run on my device.

Here's a screenshot of what my menu looks like. Note that the device (TECNO K7) is currently connected:

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I tried restarting my ADB server and I go the following error:

> Unable to locate ADB.

I have also tried re-installing the following tools multiple times, still the same outcome:

- Android SDK tools
- Android SDK Build-Tools
- Android SDK Platform-Tools

**PS: For reference, I use Mac OS and it is also important to remember that my Android studio was working perfectly fine before the update.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **Solution:**

- **Drivers not installed**: If the Android Physical device is not a Google/Nexus product than you have to download the OEM drivers of the particular model.
- **HAXM not installed properly** : Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager must have not installed properly on your computer. Try reinstalling it directly from the options available in your SDK.
- **No proper Path** : Sometimes though the files are available in the local system, The Android Studio is not guided with the accurate path name to reach the file.

Hope this will be useful to you.

Comment: I solved the problem by deleting and re-downloading my entire SDK. I eventually deduced that the problem was with my HAXM and simply re-installing this would have solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

After spending hours on this I found that the Studio update had un-assigned an SDK for my project.

Selecting File -> Project Structure, then selecting an SDK under 'Project SDK' immediately displayed the 'allow debug on this device' dialog on my phone, then within a few seconds after accepting it, the device showed up in the device list.

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

> File > Invalidate caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Before going to bellow steps make sure

> Your "Google USB Driver" package is installed ("Tools" -> "SDK Manager" -> Check "Google USB Driver" -> "Apply" -> "Ok").
>
> If you are trying to access with emulator then check "Intel x86 Emulator Accelarator(HAXM installer)" is instaled. ("Tools" -> "SDK Manager" -> Check "Intel x86 Emulator Accelarator(HAXM installer)"" -> "Apply" -> "Ok")

- Go to Tools.
- Then go to SDK Manager.
- Open SDK tools.
- Uncheck "Android SDK Platform-Tools" (On my case it was checked).
- press apply then ok.
- Again goto Tools.
- Then goto SDK Manager.
- Open SDK tools.
- check "Android SDK Platform-Tools"
- Restart Android Studio :)

Hope this will help somebody like me.

Comment: Thank you.. But then, I stated in my question that I already tried this.

Answer (score 1):

This option is definitely not the most optimal. I eventually deduced that the problem was with my HAXM and simply re-installing this would have solved the problem. If you face, this exact problem, simple re-install the HAXM in your SDK.

I hope this helps someone out there.